# Why does my my nodejs server crash even though I'm handling the supposed error that is occuring?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through my first nodejs server example, and it's mostly working. However, I noticed that the server will crash if I attempt to call an html file that does not exist. I managed to find a workaround (which has been commented out), but am very curious about why the original code  failed to behave as I expected. Before crashing, I would see the desired response, and then the server would crash with the following output:

```
Server running at http://localhost:3000
Request for /aboutuss.html by method GET
ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/Users/albertkhasky/NodeJS/node-http/public/aboutuss.html'
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/**********/NodeJS/node-http/public/aboutuss.html'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at fs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)
    at FSReqCallback.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:145:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Here is the code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Request for " + req.url + ' by method ' + req.method);


    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        var fileUrl;
        if(req.url == '/'){
            fileUrl = '/index.html';
        }else{
            fileUrl = req.url;
        }
        var filePath = path.resolve('./public' + fileUrl);
        const fileExt = path.extname(filePath);
        if(fileExt == '.html'){

            // if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            //     res.statusCode = 404;
            //     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            //     res.end('<html><body><h1>Error: 404 ' + fileUrl +  ' HTML FILE NOT FOUND </h1></body></html>');
            //     return;
            // }

            fs.access(filePath, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
                if(err){
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                    res.end('<html><body><h1>Error: 404 ' + fileUrl +  ' HTML FILE NOT FOUND </h1></body></html>');
                    console.log(err.message);
                    return;
                }
            })
        }else{
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.end('<html><body><h1>Error: 404 ' + fileUrl +  ' none HTML file not found</h1></body></html>');
            return;
        }
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
    
    }else{
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.end('<html><body><h1>Error: 404 ' + req.method +  ' not supported</h1></body></html>');
        return;
    }

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`); //variables inside the string is the reason for backticks
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason your commented out code returns a 404 is that you are passing `path`, not `filePath`so it fails every time.

the reason your `fs.access()` check fails is that it is an async call - the callback checking `err` does not happen immediately. while that check is in progress the code unconditionally creates a readstream to the non-existent path. (this is also why the deprecated call to fs.existsSync() would solve the issue if passed filePath.)

if you want to wait until the fs.access call has taken place, move the successful return (where you create the readstream) into the fs.access callback after checking for the error like:

```
    fs.access(filePath, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
        if(err){
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.end('<html><body><h1>Error: 404 ' + fileUrl +  ' HTML FILE NOT FOUND </h1></body></html>');
            console.log(err.message);
            return;
        }
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
    })
```

a more effective way of performing the operation would be to use `fs.open()` on the file, handle the error return, then `fs.createReadStream()` using the fd returned by `fs.open()`. that way you don't open the file twice nor allow the potential for race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I'm not understanding is why the code returns the expected response, but then fails immediately afterwards. If I'm understanding your explanation, it should fail immediately, without producing any output.  Why does it work just once? Also, moving the successful return does not change the behavior I've described

Comment: can you provide/update your code? if you moved the return (i.e., removed the original createReadStream() and only have it on a successful `fs.access()` call, i don't see how it can be a failure in the stream open. that shouldn't happen.

Comment: a minor note too - you'll want to use `fs.R_OK` rather than `fs.F_OK` because you want the file to be readable.

Comment: fwiw, i just changed the code (moving the code starting with `res.statusCode = 200;` and ending with `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);` to after the `if (err) {` block and the server doesn't crash for me. maybe you can add your modified code to your post?

Comment: i can't add a comment with the detail but here's the modified code that doesn't crash. if you have a problem with it, let me know the specifics. https://github.com/bmacnaughton/stackoverflow-65497995/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Your code works great. For whatever reason, this line seems to be the culprit:             fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);  In any case, I have a newfound appreciation for asynchronous behavior, which was my goal all along. Thanks so much for your many thoughtful replies!

Comment: I understand what I was doing wrong. I had this line in 2 places: fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);  Again, thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: thanks for the followup; that's what i suspected! good luck with node - async rocks.